# How can i place two divs side by side and a third div aligning with the second

Tags: html, css

I have two divs (div1 and div2) side by side and I would like to place a third div (div3) under div2.

[image]

I've tried adding a margin to div3 to try and line it up, but div1 width is dynamic. I've also tried floating div3 to the right but then the content is too far and doesn't line up with the start of div2 like in the image above

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.div1 {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="div1">
    <p> some content with unknown width</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <p> some content </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="div3">
  <p> some content that should be under div2 </p>
</div>
```

The default behaviour is div3 being under div1. I am trying to put div3 below div 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with below:

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    
    .div {
      flex-basis: 50%;
      min-height: 100px;
    }
    
    .div1 {
      background: red;
    }
    .div2 {
      background: blue;
    }
    .div3 {
      background: aqua;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div div1">div1</div>
  <div class="div div2">div2</div>
  <div class="div div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

And here is a [codepan](https://codepen.io/alperbuulut/pen/ZEzNxvK)

Comment: This does line up div3 below div2 but now everything inside wrapper is moved to the middle. Can I still keep the contents of pushed to the left?

Comment: You can remove `justify-content:flex-end` and add `margin-left:auto` to .div3 to prevent the movement.

Answer (score 1):

Use float and inline-block:

```css
[class*="div"] {
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid;
}

.div1 {
 float:left;
 margin-right: 1em;
 margin-bottom:10px; /*mandatory margin to push the div3*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="div1">
    <p> some content with unknown width</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <p> some content </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="div3">
  <p> some content that should be under div2 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**CSS Grid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) structure. In this way you can have all child elements inside a single parent container.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

/* Snippet styling */

.row > div {
  background: #6A67CE;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="div1">
    <p> some content with unknown width</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <p> some content </p>
  </div>

  <div class="div3">
    <p> some content under div2 </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: note that the use of `repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)` is invalid

Comment: Thanks. Updated the code. Seems like it does not involve using fraction units or need to use fraction units along with minmax().

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flex solution, you can use the slider to change the width of the left box to see that the width doesn't matter.

In case you are not familiar with flex, here is what happens.

`display: flex;` tells the container to act as a flex container, flex is just another display behavior just like `float`.

`flex-flow: row wrap;`, now that the container is flex, tells the children to display in a row, and wrap if necessary, not in this case.

That is all, after adding two boxes in the right div, and set some demo width and height, we are done.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let left = document.querySelector('.left')
  let range = document.querySelector('.range')
  range.addEventListener('input', e => {
    left.style.width = e.target.value + 'px'
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.container,
.right {
  border: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.left,
.one,
.two {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.one {
  min-width: 80px;
}

.two {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input class="range" type="range" min="50" max="300"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since div do not share the same parent , you could use `display:contents` and set a grid-layout one level upper , unfortunately, [`display:contents`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) is not yet supported every where .

here is an example (`body` is the wrapper and `.row` not seen anymore)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
  /* removed from the tree */
}

div {
  border: solid;
  /* show me */
  grid-column: 2;
  /* make it  the defaut column position */
  width: max-content;
}

.div1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  /*a single reset  enough here */
}

@supports (display:grid) {
  .disclaimer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="div1">
    <p> some content with unknown width</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p> some content </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <p> some content that should be under div2 </p>
</div>
<p class="disclaimer">Your browser do not support <code>display:contents</code>.</p>
```

Another possibility is the table-layout algorythm

example with display:table (widely supported) , but every cell of each columns are of the same width.

```css
body {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.div3,
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row>div,
.div3>p,
.div3::before {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
}

.div3::before {/* it stands in column 1 */
  content: '';
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="div1">
    <p> some content with unknown width</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p> some content </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <p> some content that should be under div2 </p>
</div>
```

Nothing is perfect ;)

Answer (score -1):

hi i coded this if that helps

```css
.first-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
    
.first-container div{
  margin: 10px;
}
    
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-container">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="second">second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
</div>
```